# GetX with GridView: Last Element Always Disappears

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-getx

I'm seeing strange behavior with GetX and a GridView, where the elements of the view don't repaint correctly. Here's what happens:

1. Grid is populated with a list of elements [A, B, C, and D]
2. I remove element A (the background logic reflects this).
3. From the UI prospective, it appears that the last element in the list is removed. (This is in fact not true.)
4. Upon forced page refresh, the correct UI elements are present.

This occurs with logic.obx, Obx, and GetBuilder.

Comment: That's not the question though @RandalSchwartz. Everyone can use the tools they want to use, that's my opinion. I don't like React, or Django, but I don't go off telling people to not use it when they're trying to fix a problem.

Comment: Most problems people have with GetX can be removed by migrating away from GetX.  I'm trying help people towards their solution.

Comment: The keywords in your question is _strange behavior_ and _don't repaint correctly_, and you mentioned that it occurs with three of GetX APIs, indicating that they're probably GetX problems, in which Randal's suggestion is valid.